# transfer data from winforms to chrome via chrome extension

Tags: winforms, google-chrome

I have a windows application in c# in which i am getting the Html of the page opened in chrome through a chrome extension
this is how i wrote a chrome extension

**background.js**

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

```
if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "jquery.min.js" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "content.js" }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { text: tab }, function (data) {
                alert("hi");
                chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(data.WindowId, function (response) {                        
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        if ((response[i].index + 1) == data.Tab) {
                            chrome.tabs.update(response[i].id, { selected: true });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

});

**Content.js**

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

```
$.post(listener, { dom: document.all[0].outerHTML }, function (data) {

});
```

});

Now I need to have a button in by winform to send some data to chrome. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It, We can use native messaging app to interact with chrome through native app messaging

> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging